# Text formatting not working with qTranslate plugin

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I am creating a multilingual website using wordpress as CMS.

i am using qTranslate plugin for multi language support. As soon as i enable the plugin, all formatting of text is lost. i.e. all paragraphs in the editor are merged into a single paragraph.

I have enabled this option in settings: "WordPress should correct invalidly nested XHTML automatically" but there is no change.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:
http://www.teslina.com/en/748/wordpress/qtranslate-code-syntax-bugfix/

However i suspect that the code added in plugin will be removed when it's updated.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code at the end of **wp-content\themes\your-theme-name\functions.php**:

```
//************************** PATCH START *****************************

// Fix for qTranslate plugin (that does not retain formatting in pages)

if('html' != wp_default_editor()) {
                remove_filter('the_editor_content', 'wp_richedit_pre');
                add_filter('the_editor_content', 'wp_htmledit_pre');
        }
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
if ( ! function_exists('tmce_replace') ) {
        function tmce_replace() {
                $tadv_options = get_option('tadv_options', array());
                $tadv_plugins = get_option('tadv_plugins', array());    
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( typeof(jQuery) != 'undefined' ) {
  jQuery('body').bind('afterPreWpautop', function(e, o){
    o.data = o.unfiltered
    .replace(/caption\]\ +?<\/object>/g, function(a) {
      return a.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, ' ');
    });
  }).bind('afterWpautop', function(e, o){
    o.data = o.unfiltered;
  });
}
</script>
<?php
        }
        add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', 'tmce_replace' );
}
function teslina_tinymce_config( $init ) { 
    $init['remove_linebreaks'] = false;
    $init['apply_source_formatting'] = true;
    $init['preformatted'] = true;
    $init['remove_redundant_brs'] = false;    
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'teslina_tinymce_config');


//************************** PATCH END *******************************
```

Answer (score 0):

write simple post in html mode to test like this :

```
<p>lorem</p>
<p>ipsum</p>
```

There is filter in wordpress to format text (plugin, or functions.php) try to find them, else try another plugin like Polylang.